# Add second WooCommerce product to cart via AJAX with checkbox checked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have unsuccessfully been trying every-which-way to add a conditional second product to the cart on "Add To Cart" if checkbox checked.

I have an order form, and I would like to add a second product to the cart if a checkbox is checked. I started by attempting to add the value through the session or cookie. This worked on Single Product pages, but not with the Add To Cart shortcode [add_to_cart id="XX"]. I thought AJAX was my best chance, but I'm inexperienced with AJAX and can't tell if it's the shortcode or me.

Here is my cheap way to get to Add to Cart on a checkbox submission.

Input:

```
function sample_input(){

        echo '
            <form id="myform" action="">
            Check this box: 
            <input type="checkbox" id="add-to-cart" name="16379" /><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div></form>
                ';
}
```

Load scripts:

```
    function enqueue_scripts_styles_init() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/ajax-testing-script.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), 1.0 ); // jQuery will be included automatically
        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting ajaxurl
    }
    add_action('init', 'enqueue_scripts_styles_init');
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){

    send_data = function(item) {

        $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {

            dataType: "json",
            data: {'item' : item},
            type: "POST",
            cache: false

        }).done(function(data, status, xml) {

            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(obj.success);

        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }).always(function() {
        });

    }


    $("#show").click(function() {

        var $check = $('input#item');

        if ($check.is(":checked")) {
            alert("Yes");
            send_data($check.val()); 
        } else {
            alert("box is not checked");
        }


    });


});
```

This is a successful method, and gets me the correct product added to cart, a "Yes" alert plus a second alert of 'undefined'. So I think somewhere the AJAX is broken, since I get the 'undefined' alert. Plus, when I change the `id`, `name`, and `value` on the checkbox to `id="item" name="item" value="AddOnProduct"` and rely on PHP to deliver the Add To Cart, I get no results from the `send_data = function(item) {}`

If I change the `submit` button to `do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="517"]')`, I get the failed alert "box is not checked" and only product ID is added to the cart. So I think the AJAX isn't set up to handle the add to cart function and my ajax at the same time. In the end, this is what the final code should be doing:

```
    echo '
        <form id="myform" action="">
        Check this box: 
        <input type="checkbox" id="item" name="item" value="AddOnProduct" />
<div id="show">' . do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="517"]') . '</div></form>';
```

PHP:

```
    function ajax_action_stuff() {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['item'])) {
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 16379 ); //2nd product
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff' );
```

On `(#show)click()` the ajax should send the product ID to cart and capture a second ID to send to the cart, if "item" was checked. I think if I could successfully pass the value back to PHP I could execute the command in my ajax function. Is it the AJAX or the shortcode add-to-cart?

Comment: Are you trying to add product A if product B is on the cart?

Comment: No. If checkbox is checked, I want to add Product B to the cart when the Product A add to cart button is clicked. It's an add-on product.